# Where is the Wiener filter implemented by Scipy derived from?

Tags: python, scipy, wiener-filter

I am using the Wiener Filter to do speech enhancement (1D data) and while I see the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L441), I'm unsure where it was derived from. Is there an academic or authoritative source that it came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Pauli Virtanen](https://github.com/pv) in a [Github issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11415):

> Reading https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/signal.html#wiener-filter it's probably the same as wiener2 in Octave/Matlab, whose reference points to Lim, Jae S., Two-Dimensional Signal and Image Processing, Englewood Cliffs, NJ, Prentice Hall, 1990, p. 548.